# Efficient way to reduce a vectors magnitude by a specific length?

Tags: c++, math, vector, linear-algebra

Lets say I have an arbitrary vector A. What is the most efficient way to reducing that vectors magnitude by arbitrary amount?

My current method is as follows:

```
Vector shortenLength(Vector A, float reductionLength) {

    Vector B = A;
    B.normalize();
    B *= reductionLength;
    return A - B;

}
```

Is there a more efficent way to do this? Possibly removing the square root required to normalize B...

Comment: Oh this is a math vector, not a C++ vector.  I was confused.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to normalize without doing a square root for the general case, and every other operation should be fast.  I don't think you're going to beat that speed except by avoiding copies.

Comment: It depends on how the vector is represented. If it were a 2-D vector stored as angle and magnitude, then this would be trivial. You don't say how your `Vector` class represents vectors internally or even if you have access to the data. The answer would depend on that.

Comment: "by" or "to" an arbitrary amount?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you have a vector `A`, and want another vector which points in the same direction as `A`, but is shorter by `reductionLength`, right?

Does the `Vector` interface have something like a "length" member function (returning the length of the vector)? Then I think the following should be more efficient:

```
Vector shortenLength(Vector A, float reductionLength) 
{
    Vector B = A;
    B *= (1 - reductionLength/A.length());
    return B;
}
```

Comment: Usually "normalizing" a vector means "same direction, but length of 1.  His code is making a vector that is the same direction, with a length of "reductionlength".  The text implies that the code is entirely wrong though.

Comment: @MooingDuck: He is *subtracting* a vector which he obtained by first normalizing and then multiplying with `reductionLength` *from the original vector.* Which means he obtains a vector which points in the same direction, but is shorter by `reductionLength` (assuming the original vector was longer than `reductionLength` to begin with).

Comment: oh yeah, forgot that last line.  Not sure how that happened.

Comment: @celtschk I know this is from a few years ago, but just wondering: how is this any different from the OP's code snippet? You simply decompose the `normalize()` member function into a separate `length()` member function and a division operation. Both methods still require a square root, so why is yours any faster / more efficient?

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast: In the original code, each element of $B$ is multiplied *twice* with a factor; once in `normalize`, and once when multiplying with `reduction_length`. In my code, the multiplication only occurs once per element.

Comment: Why copy the vector twice, though?

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah, so I was using the word correctly. It's "normaizing" in German, but in English I've only ever heard 'unit vector' as in `unitV(vec)`. The word "normalize" generates great expressions like "normalized normal vector", though ;)

Comment: @PostSelf: It's a long time since I wrote it, but I probably had named return value optimization in mind. IIRC that doesn't work if a parameter is returned.

Answer (score 7):

If you're going to scale a vector by multiplying it by a scalar value, you should *not* normalize.  Not for efficiency reasons; because the outcome isn't what you probably want.

Let's say you have a vector that looks like this:

```
v = (3, 4)
```

Its magnitude is `sqrt(3^2 + 4^2) = 5`.  So let's normalize it:

```
n = (0.6, 0.8)
```

This vector has magnitude 1; it's a unit vector.

So if you "shorten" each one by a factor of 0.5, what do you get?

```
shortened v = (3, 4) * 0.5 = (1.5, 2.0)
```

Now let's normalize it by its magnitude sqrt(6.25):

```
normalized(shortened v) = (1.5/2.5, 2/2.5) = (0.6, 0.8)
```

If we do the same thing to the unit vector:

```
shortened(normalized v) = (0.6, 0.8) * 0.5 = (0.3, 0.4)
```

These are not the same thing at all.  Your method does two things, and they aren't commutative.

Comment: I can't imagine why this would be voted down.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that he nowhere stated nor implied that he wants to multiply his vector by the scalar value `reductionLength`. In other words, your answer doesn't answer his question. (BTW, I'm not the one who voted you down.)

Comment: What do you imagine that "*=" operator is doing to that vector?  It certainly is implied if you know something about vectors.

Comment: Just because at *one step* he multiplies an *auxiliary vector* by this number doesn't imply that his *ultimate goal* is to multiply the *original vector* by this amount.

Comment: In C, Java, and C# the "#=" operator works on the left-hand side object when # is +, -, *, /, and others.  I'm assuming that it's how the *= operator was overloaded for this C++ Vector class.  And the name of the method, shortenLength, is highly suggestive to me.

Comment: I'm explaining what I'm thinking.